# Rails 4: X-Accel-Redirect does not set Content-Length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I cannot seem to set the Content-Length of files that are downloaded from my Rails app. Here is a typical set of headers I get when I download something:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 29 Jul 2016 07:11:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/zip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="no2.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["blablabla"]
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Request-Id: fec224f9-d00c-410b-9ba6-1cd402e51b9f
X-Runtime: 9.224241
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
```

I noticed that Transfer-Encoding is also set to chunked. I am using X-Accel-Redirect and I think there must be some problem with that.

Here are my nginx settings:

```
location /stuff/ {
    internal;
    root /home/rails/blablabla;
}
location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping "/home/rails/blablabla/stuff/=/stuff/";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

Controller:

```
def download
  file = @post.zip_location
  send_file file
end
```

I've tried:

- setting `response.headers['Content-Length'] = file.size.to_s`
- setting `response.headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'`
- setting `proxy_set_header X-Accel-Buffering no;` in nginx
- setting `proxy_buffering off;` in nginx

Nothing works... Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where is `x-accel-redirect` in your code.

Comment: It's in Rails by default already: `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX` in `config/environments/production.rb`. I assume that should work already since I no longer get logs like 'Missing X-Accel-Redirect' anymore.